# Debugging And Stepping Through Code With Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor, webstorm, rubymine, e2e-testing

I was previously writing/running end to end tests in C# with Visual Studio and Selenium. I had the ability to debug a test and step through the test while seeing the steps happening in Chrome.

With that said, I am now trying to get a RubyMine or WebStorm/Protractor environment to do the same thing.

The best I can do now is

- put a focus on the test by putting an "f" in the it statements to ignore the rest of the tests in the suite.
- I set a break point and debug
- The test begins and starts up the browser
- hits the break point while the browser says:

  ```
  {"build": "##BUILD_NUMBER##","api": "http://api:3000","ws": "ws://api:3001"}
  ```
- I can finish stepping through the test, and THEN the test runs in the browser. Basically after the test already ran. Not while I am steping through it.

If I come to a click element statement and step through it, I should see it happen in the browser. Or at least I could in VS.

Along with that, each test has run buttons to the right of the line numbers. When I try to run/debug with those, it seems to only want to use Karma and not protractor.

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried this way? There are some directions on how to setup webstorm toward the end. https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/debugging.md